# Parallelize Depth First Search C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, depth-first-search

I was writing a program for HiQ and I was using this Depth First Search loop. However I wanted to do it parallel with MPI, but what can I do to make a depth first search parallel?

```
bool FindSolution(ConfigType PuzzleConfig ) // Depth-First Search for sol to puzzle
{

if (PuzzleConfig == SolutionConfig) return true;    

bool SolutionFound = false;

Mark(PuzzleConfig);

// For all configurations adjacent to current Puzzle Configuration (uses brute-force)
for (short from=1; !SolutionFound && from<=NUMHOLES; from++)
{
    for (short to=1; !SolutionFound && to<=NUMHOLES; to++)
    {
        JumpType jump = {from,to};
        if ( ValidJump(jump, PuzzleConfig) )
        {
            ConfigType NewConfig = FindNewConfig(jump, PuzzleConfig);
            if ( !Marked(NewConfig) )
            {
                SolutionFound = FindSolution( NewConfig );  // Recursive call for Depth-First Search
                if (SolutionFound)
                    JumpStack.push(jump);
            }
        }
    }
}

return SolutionFound;
}
```

Comment: One way to parallelize code is to push work on a queue and have multiple threads pull work off the queue.

Answer (score 2):

MPI is useful when you can define the concrete topology of the parallel computing elements in advance, and can partition the work across the computing elements largely in advance of execution.  Then each element "knows" where the other elements are, and roughly what they are doing, and thus can decide which it should send messages to in order to issue an MPI send.  Similarly, the receiving elements have to "know" that they are about recieve a message, in order to issue an MPI recieve.

A depth first search is arguably tree like, so you know the abstract topology... but you don't know the actual shape of of the tree, and thus no processor knows what nodes it is associated with in advance.  So its very hard to figure out which processors should send, and which should recieve.  I don't think MPI is your friend for this.

It is probably better to have a worklist style algorithm, which contains nodes of the expanding tree to search.  Then each processor can go to the worklist, get a node, expand that node into children, and place the children back in work list.   This will give a frontier that expands randomly rather than depth first.

To go depth first, a node looking for work wants the work queue to give it the *deepest* expanded node, so the work list should act something like a priority queue. This way the deepest nodes are expanded by processors first, giving a depth first flavor.

It may be easiest to achieve this effect by having a processor that expands a tree node, pushed the expanded set on top of the worklist as set; then each processor takes work from the set on top of the worklist.  When a processor finds a set on top of the worklist empty, it can pop the set an try again.

A *work stealing* version gives you this kind of effect.  A first processor generates a set of work; if it has lots of work when it generates a child node of some node P, it stops generating children of P, leaving a bit work to generate the rest of the children of P, and switches its attention to an already generated child of P.  This gives the depth-first effect.  Other nodes execute the same way when they have work; when they don't, they go steal a work list entry from another node, which causes them to start searching down a subtree.